# GRUB starts in grub> command line after reboot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub

After converting a physical Ubuntu_18.04 machine into a virtual one (ESXi under vCenter control), I encountered the following window appearing when booting.

[image: first]

After I enter the “exit” command, the system loads the normal menu and then everything is ok.

[image: second]

How to make the bootloader immediately load the menu without entering the command line and typing "exit"?

P.S. I tried boot-rescue utility, it says it was successful, but it doesn’t help.

sudo efibootmgr -v
[image: efibootmgr]

UPD.
[image]

If i changing Bootorder to 0003 in sudo efibootmgr -o 0003,000A,0000,0001,0002,0004,0009,0005,0006,0007,0008
BootCurrent: 0003
BootOrder: 0003,000A,0000,0001,0002,0004,0009,0005,0006,0007,0008
[image]
won't load at all

It doesn’t help.

Comment: What is the platform on which the Ubuntu VM is running? VMware Vcenter? VMware workstation player? VMware Workstation Pro? Hyper V? What are the settings for the VM on the platform? What do the bootlogs say? Add this information to the question and do not post it as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the bootorder order did not help.
But completely removing the Ubuntu menu item from efi helped.

[image]

Just in case, I ran the update-grub2 command after a successful download.

Now the output of the “efibootmgr -v” command looks like this
[image]

**What can I do to ensure that the bootloader does not get damaged during further work?**

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please edit your post so that the pictures are correctly displayed. Also, if you have a new question, please don't post it in the answer section, but create a new one. You can link to this question if you think this helps establish context.

Answer (score 0):

Please run `lsblk -o +HCTL,PARTUUID` in a wide terminal window.

Your `efibootmgr -v` output indicates the following things:

- `BootCurrent: 0003` indicates the system booted successfully using the `Boot0003` line.
- `BootOrder` indicates that the successful `Boot0003` was 5th in the overall boot order
- The `Boot0003` line identifies the disk as `.../SCSI(3,0)`, so to identify the disk that has the working version of GRUB, look at the `HCTL` field of the above-mentioned `lsblk` command and see which disk includes the number 3 in its HCTL field.
- The first entry in BootOrder, `Boot000A`, specifies the partition to boot from using a PARTUUID value of `75d67bdc-e92a-47f3-6816-e6f03bed26e9`: look at the `PARTUUID` field of the `lsblk` output to identify the disk.

It seems that one of the boot entries before `0003` in the boot order contains a bad installation of GRUB. Perhaps it is a remnant of an earlier installation, or perhaps the filesystem UUID it uses to find the `/boot/grub` directory was changed in the cloning process. Once you exit that GRUB instance, the firmware proceeds further in the boot order list, until it finds a valid bootloader at the `Boot0003` entry. This is probably at a fallback/removable media path, i.e. at `EFI/BOOT/BOOTx64.efi` of whatever partition it's located on.

A "perfect" fix would probably be to identify the Linux device name of the disk that contains your ESP partition (which should be mounted at `/boot/efi/`), and then run:

```
sudo grub-install --target=x86_64-efi /dev/sdX
```

where `/dev/sdX` should be replaced with the name of the whole-disk device that contains the ESP partition. That should automatically re-write GRUB to the ESP partition, and also update the `efibootmgr -v` list to properly point to the active GRUB instance.

If you cannot identify the disk, you can use the following command instead as a workaround:

```
sudo efibootmgr --bootorder 0003,000A,0000,0001,0002,0004,0005,0006,0007,0008,0009
```

This will tell the firmware to place the working boot entry as the first one in the boot order, avoiding the need to exit out of the non-working one. It should fix the immediate issue, but there might be problems later in installing kernel or GRUB updates or making them effective, since there will be no certainty that the GRUB instance that successfully boots the system is the same one that will be updated by the package management system.

Comment: it doesn`t help. I updated the question